# Why can’t protected members be used by friends of derived classes?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, friend, protected, derived-class

The C++ standard states in [[class.access/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#1) (emphasis mine):

> A member of a class can be
>
> - private; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.
> - protected; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared, by classes derived from that class, **and by their friends (see [class.protected]).**
> - public; that is, its name can be used anywhere without access restriction.

So why does the compiler raise this error in the following C++ program?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class B {
  protected:
    static int const i = 1;
};

class D: public B {
  public:
    void f();
    friend void g();
};

void D::f() {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.i;  // OK
}

void g() {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.i;  // error: 'i' is a protected member of 'B'
}

int main() {
  D d;
  d.f();
  g();
  return 0;
}
```

Notice that the protected data member `B::i` is declared *static* not to be subject to the further restrictions specific to protected *non-static* members in [[class.access/class.protected-1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#class.protected-1) which would also raise the same error at the `b.i` access in the `D::f` member function as that in the `g` function.

*Note.* — I am using C++ 17 on the Clang 9.0.0 compiler.

Comment: fyi clang fails; g++ and MSVC compile - live: https://godbolt.org/z/TkmnbW   You might want to add the [language-lawyer] tag

Comment: Also, if you define `g` inline (and modify it slightly so it can be called via ADL) then clang compiles too: https://godbolt.org/z/_2rEdA Seems like a clang bug to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a specification issue. The part that I have quoted is not in sync with another part which specifies the new correct behaviour followed by Clang (but not GCC nor MSVC surprisingly), [[class.access/base-5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#base-5) (emphasis mine):

> A member m is accessible at the point R when named in class N if
>
> - m as a member of N is public, or
> - m as a member of N is private, and R occurs in a member or friend of class N, or
> - m as a member of N is protected, and R occurs in a member or friend of class N, **or in a member of a class P derived from N,** where m as a member of P is public, private, or protected, or

- there exists a base class B of N that is accessible at R, and m is accessible at R when named in class B.

Here *friend* is not mentioned for the derived class. But it used to be. It has been removed in C++ 17 because of defect report [CWG 1873](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1873) (emphasis mine):

> Protected member access from derived class friends
>
> Section: 14.2  [class.access.base]     Status: CD4     Submitter:
> Richard Smith     Date: 2014-02-18
>
> [Moved to DR at the May, 2015
> meeting.]
>
> According to 14.2 [class.access.base] paragraph 5,
>
> A member m is accessible at the point R when named in class N if
>
> - …
> - m as a member of N is protected, and R occurs in a member or friend of
>   class N, or in a member or friend of a class P derived from N, where m
>   as a member of P is public, private, or protected, or
> - …
>
> The granting of access via class P is troubling. At the least, there
> should be a restriction that P be visible at R. Alternatively, this
> portion of the rule could be removed altogether; this provision does
> not appear to be widely used in existing code and such references can
> be easily converted to use P instead of N for naming the member.
>
> Notes from the June, 2014 meeting:
>
> CWG noted that removing the friend provision would introduce an
> undesirable asymmetry between member functions of P and its friends.
> Instead, the intent is to require P to be a complete type at R.
>
> Notes from the November, 2014 meeting:
>
> Although the asymmetry is unfortunate, the difference between a
> reference in a member function and a reference in a friend is that the
> member function concretely determines which P is in view, while the
> friend could be befriended by a class that is a specialization of a
> class template and thus would require instantiations that would not
> otherwise occur. CWG thus decided simply to eliminate the friend case.
>
> Proposed resolution, November, 2014:
>
> Change bullet 5.3 of 14.2 [class.access.base] as follows:
>
> A member m is accessible at the point R when named in class N if
>
> - …
> - m as a member of N is protected, and R occurs in a member or friend of
>   class N, **or in a member <strike>or friend</strike> of a class P derived from N,** where m
>   as a member of P is public, private, or protected, or
> - there exists…

I have filed a pull request on GitHub to correct this inconsistency: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3672

Comment: agree with the DR resolution, it seems bogus that access control could be subverted in this way